# Blogger: How to use thumbnails/video thumbnails?

Tags: thumbnails, blogger, video-thumbnails

I've  seen many Blogger templates and sites use thumbnails by taking the first image of the post and using that as a thumbnail on the homepage. I'm writing my own Blogger template from scratch (http://test.wwsalmon.com/) and I want to use thumbnails, but I have no idea how to. Also, I want to be able to have mini video players for embedded YouTube videos in the post. Can somebody help me? What code to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can link to and use first image as thumbnail with code below

```
<img class='' expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl' alt=""/>
```

here `data:post.firstImageUrl` provides the link to first image in post.

make sure to use `expr:src=""` instead of `src=""`